# Convert EDT to UTC to EDT

Tags: python, datetime

I have a EDT datetime and its corresponding UTC datetime.

I want to know how to convert the UTC datetime back to EDT datetime using the offset.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import dateutil.tz

dt = parse('Tue Apr 26 2016 08:32:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)')
localtz = dateutil.tz.tzlocal()

print 'offset == ',localtz.utcoffset(dt) #Get the offset
print 'tzname == ',dt.tzname() #Get the Tzname

utc_dt = dt.utcnow() #Get the UTC datetime
print 'utcnow == ',utc_dt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried saving the tzinfo of the datetime object before you convert, and then just to revert back to it?

```
timezone = dt.tzinfo
```

to convert back:

```
dt.astimezone(tz=timezone)
```

Comment: that works, Is there a way for me to re-create the tzinfo object..I want to store it in the database(tzinfo attribubtes) and will use that information later to convert it

Comment: To be honest, I have no clue!  I'm sure you can, but I have never tried.